# htaccess redirect causes loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have links that look like this that are located on websites that point back to us:
http://www.example.com/campaign

On our website we have a javascript that changes the phone numbers whenever the URL string shows the phone number parameter.
Example: http://www.example.com/campaign?tfid=8885551212 (this would change all the phone numbers to 888-555-1212)

I've tried to set a 301 redirect in htaccess to append the "?tfid=8885551212" string such as this:

```
Redirect 301 /campaign http://www.example.com/campaign?tfid=8885551212
```

The problem is that this causes a redirect loop, so I'm wondering if there's a way to do this so it won't cause the loop?

Comment: I'm not experienced enough in .htaccess rules to know if this is too broad, but it certainly looks a little vague. Could you show us examples of what you've tried already, from your .htaccess files?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't illustrate the code in a comment, but I need somebody that has a deep understanding of htaccess that might know the correct code to append the ?tfid=8885551212  query string without causing a redirect loop in a 301 or 302 redirect. I'm thinking the correct way to do this might be to use ReWrite, but I can't find a way to make it append the query string and trigger the javascript.

Comment: You mention of redirecting `/campaign` pages, whereas; the code deals with `/terms`

Comment: just realized that and corrected the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by moving a ReWrite condition to the top of the htaccess file *before* anything else could interfere with it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^campaign1$ http://www.example.com/campaign1?tfid=8885551212 [L,NE,R=301]
```